# Is it possible to manipulate a dataframe created through Pandas using SQL?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, sqlalchemy

So I'm trying to create a python script that allows me to perform SQL manipulations on a dataframe (masterfile) I created using pandas. The dataframe draws its contents from the csv files found in a specific folder.

I was able to successfully create everything else, but I am having trouble with the SQL manipulation part. I am trying to use the dataframe as the "database" where I will pull the data using my SQL query but I am getting a "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cursor' " error.

I'm not really seeing a lot of examples for pandas.read_sql_query() so I am having a difficult time on understanding how I will use my dataframe in it.

```
import os 
import glob 
import pandas

os.chdir("SOMECENSOREDDIRECTORY")

all_csv = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format('csv')) if i != 'Masterfile.csv']

edited_files = [] 
for i in all_csv:
    df = pandas.read_csv(i)
    df["file_name"] = i.split('.')[0]
    edited_files.append(df)

masterfile = pandas.concat(edited_files, sort=False)

print("Data fields are as shown below:") 
print(masterfile.iloc[0])

sql_query = "SELECT Country, file_name as Year, Happiness_Score FROM masterfile WHERE Country = 'Switzerland'"
            
output = pandas.read_sql_query(sql_query, masterfile)

output.to_csv('data_pull')
```

I know this part is wrong, but this is the concept I am trying to get to work but don't know how:

```
output = pandas.read_sql_query(sql_query, masterfile)
```

I appreciate any help I can get! I am a self-thought python programmer by the way, so I might be missing some general rule or something. Thanks!

Edit: replaced "slice" with "manipulate" because I realized I didn't want to just slice it. Also fixed some alignment issues on my code block.

Answer (score 0):

It's is possible to slice dataframe Which created through Pandas and SQL You can use loc function of pandas to slice dataframe.
`pd.df.loc[row,colums]`

Comment: I see, however I am also actually trying to make it work with SQL so that I can perform more complex data manipulations on the dataframe the way SQL allows.

Comment: You can convert SQL to Pandas Dataframe and Then You can Continue.